# Why does Azure Application Insights populates the “Dependencies” panel instead of the “Operations” one, when I use TelemetryClient.StartOperation()?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring, apm, azure-monitor

Using the `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.*` NuGet packages, I instructed my code to inject telemetry data to Azure Application Insights as following:

```
using (myTelemetryClient.StartOperation<DependencyTelemetry>("Processing"))
{
   try
   {
      ...
   }
   catch (Exception exception)
   {
      myTelemetryClient.TrackException(exception);
   }
}
```

However, in the Azure portal, I see the `Processing` message being shown under the **Dependencies** panel, not the to-me-more-appropriate **Operations** one:

[image]

The Operations panel is empty. Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK the operations blade only takes in account request operations. So `myTelemetryClient.StartOperation<RequestTelemetry>("Processing")` should cause the exception to be shown on the operations tab.

Most times, dependency telemetry is also part of an operation. If all those failed dependencies would also appear on the operations tab the dependencies tab would be obsolete. Maybe the operations tab should be named requests or request operations :-)